# Getting Values out of Websocket Functions

Tags: javascript, websocket, java-websocket

I am working on a project which needs to get communication from C++ code to JavaScript on a webserver. Currently, I have data sending properly and it's being received but the issue is that I cant use the data outside of the inner(onmessage) function. This still works fine to overwrite elements of the webpage, but the charts I'm trying to build cant get the live data. If I put the code for the chart inside the inner function the entire program freezes and I can't get the variable out of the function for me to use it in the parent either. Right now, I just want to get the data out of the inner function so I can use it. So, is there any way for me to pull that data out of the inner function and use it in the parent function?

Here is my code:

```
{
     var x;

     var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:10011/');
     ws.onmessage = function(event) 
     {    
         x = event.data;
         var testing = document.getElementById('InnerFunctionOutput');
         testing.innerHTML = "Run Time: " + x;
     }

     var testing = document.getElementById('ParentFunctionOutput');
     testing.innerHTML = "Run Time: " + x;
}
```

When I run this code the output from the inner function is the constant stream of data and the output from the parent is a constant 1. If anyone could help me find a solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

One alternative solution is to put the functions for the charts inside the websocket function. That way, I wouldn't have to get data out of the function. however, this solution has its own set of problems. I will put a link below to a thread where I ask about this alternate solution if you are interested in that part.

[Plotly and Websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66104834/plotly-and-websockets)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem. To get the data out of the websocket function I overwrote a text element on the page and simply made that element invisible. After that, just read the text element in order to get it into the rest of the code. However, there could be a better way of doing this so please let me knw if there is.

Also, there is one issue I ran into with this solution. When I originally tried this with normal formatting `document.getElementById('some id').innerHTML = some data;` it didn't work. But when with adding "window" to the beginning `window.document.getElementById('some id').innerHTML = some data;` it just worked.